# J Primes Enumeration

Tags: j, sieve

J will answer the n-th prime via p:n.

If I ask for the 100 millionth prime I get an almost instant answer.  I cannot imagine J is sieving for that prime that quickly, but neither looking it up in a table as that table would be around 1GB in size.

There are equations giving approximations to the number of primes to a bound, but they are only approximations.

How is J finding the answer so quickly ?

Comment: I'm no expert, but looking at `v2.c`, it looks like J has a lot of big prime tables built into it, and maybe sieves an additional bunch of them on start-up. Also, I bet on a modern computer, with a clever algorithm that makes a lot of "space-for-time sacrifices", finding the 100 millionth prime takes a lot less time than you think!

Comment: Some insight can be gained from this 2001 forum post by Roger Hui. I would guess that more advanced techniques have been put into play in the last 14 years. http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/general/2001-August/007334.html

Answer (score 6):

## J uses a table to start, then calculates

> NOTE! This is speculation, based on benchmarks (shown below).

If you want to quickly try for yourself, try the following:

```
p:1e8   NB. near-instant
p:1e8-1 NB. noticeable pause
```

The low points on the graph are where J looks up the prime in a table.  After that, J is calculating the value *from a particular starting point* so it doesn't have to calculate the entire thing.  So some lucky primes will be constant time (simple table lookup) but generally there's first a table lookup, and then a calculation.  But happily, it calculates starting from the previous table lookup instead of calculating the entire value.

### Benchmarks

I did some benchmarking to see how `p:` performs on my machine (iMac i5, 16G RAM).  I'm using J803.  The results are interesting.  I'm *guessing* the sawtooth pattern in the time plots (visible on the 'up to 2e5' plot) is lookup table related, while the overall log-ish shape (visible on the 'up to 1e7' plot) is CPU related.

```
NB. my test script
ts=:3 : 0
  a=.y
  while. a do.
  c=.timespacex 'p:(1e4*a)'  NB. 1000 times a
  a=.<:a
  b=.c;b
  end.
  }:b
)

a =: ts 200

require'plot'
plot >0{each a  NB. time
plot >1{each a  NB. space
```

## (`p:` up to 2e5)

### time

[image: time]

### space

[image: space]

## (`p:` up to 1e7)

### time

[image: bigtime]

### space

[image: bigspace]

During these runs one core was hovering around 100%:
[image: cpu]

Also, the [voc](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dpco.htm) page states:

> Currently, arguments larger than 2^31 are tested to be prime according to a probabilistic algorithm (Miller-Rabin).

And in addition to a prime lookup table as @Mauris points out, `v2.c` contains this function:

```
static F1(jtdetmr){A z;B*zv;I d,h,i,n,wn,*wv;
 RZ(w=vi(w));
 wn=AN(w); wv=AV(w);
 GA(z,B01,wn,AR(w),AS(w)); zv=BAV(z);
 for(i=0;i<wn;++i){
  n=*wv++;
  if(1>=n||!(1&n)||0==n%3||0==n%5){*zv++=0; continue;}
  h=0; d=n-1; while(!(1&d)){++h; d>>=1;}
  if     (n< 9080191)*zv++=spspd(31,n,d,h)&&spspd(73,n,d,h);
  else if(n<94906266)*zv++=spspd(2 ,n,d,h)&&spspd( 7,n,d,h)&&spspd(61,n,d,h);
  else               *zv++=spspx(2 ,n,d,h)&&spspx( 7,n,d,h)&&spspx(61,n,d,h);
 }
 RE(0); R z;
}    /* deterministic Miller-Rabin */
```